# No matching step definition found for the step when combining with normal mstests

Tags: c#, mstest, specflow

We have developed a framework for writing unit and integration tests against our application which handles a lot of our basics like automatically cleaning up after itself and such.  When we started writing SpecFlow tests against the same application, we extended our previous framework so that we wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

This works great... normally.  What we've found is that when we run large groups of these tests together (combining both normal MSTests and SpecFlow generated tests), *sometimes* the SpecFlow tests will fail with the, "No matching step definition found." errors.

I can run any of the above tests individually, and they work fine.  I can even grab chunks of the tests, and they'll work fine.  Side note: Running all these tests together with debugger attached doesn’t cause the failure to happen.

Comment: I think best is to discuss this in an issue on GitHub. Please open one hear: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc

Please provide some feature files/scenarios and the bindings where you get this error. Thanks!

Comment: I posted the issue to Github here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1184  I'm going to keep this article here as well, in case someone else has seen this problem before, and so that I can hopefully post a resolution if one is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handful of our tests were messing with the appconfig like so:

```
AppConfig.Change("SomeTestConfig.config");
```

This was messing up SpecFlow such that it couldn't find the additional assemblies to load bindings from.